# Detect multiple keys in confbridge asterisk 11

Tags: asterisk

How can I detect multiple keys in a conference in confbridge application. Right now I can only detect a single key number digit. How can I detect a 2 digit or 3 digit number for example 45 or 454.
Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: When you say 'detect multiple keys', do you mean via the ConfBridge configuration for in-conference DTMF menus? Or do you have an AMI client that is attempting to listen for the AMI DTMF events?

Comment: yes I want to perform a dialplan action via "Confbridge Configuration for in-conference DTMF menus" if someone press 45 or 56.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect 4, record that detection, detect next digit(5), record it again.

Do that as many times as you need.

Comment: He's referring to the in-conference DTMF menus in ConfBridge. There is nothing to use to 'record the DTMF' in that case, as all of the DTMF handling and mapping that to an in conference action occurs in the application itself.

Comment: No. It allow go some context, see docs. In that context you can record action and return back to conf. I am sure, i did action like described.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it's completely possible to have DTMF menus that are triggered based on multiple DTMF keys presses.

Example:

```
[general]

[user_profile]
type = user
admin = no
pin = 1111
marked = yes
startmuted = no
announce_user_count = yes
announce_user_count_all = 1
announce_join_leave = yes

[user_menu]
type = menu
1 = toggle_mute
201 = leave_conference

[default_bridge]
type = bridge

[default_user]
type = user
```

In this log snippet, you can see the user press '201' to leave the conference:

```
[Feb 21 22:28:16] VERBOSE[18929][C-00000001] pbx.c:     -- Executing [user_profile@confbridge:1] NoOp("SIP/ast2_g722-00000001", "") in new stack
[Feb 21 22:28:16] VERBOSE[18929][C-00000001] pbx.c:     -- Executing [user_profile@confbridge:2] ConfBridge("SIP/ast2_g722-00000001", "1,,user_profile,user_menu") in new stack
[Feb 21 22:28:26] VERBOSE[18929][C-00000001] file.c:     -- <SIP/ast2_g722-00000001> Playing 'conf-onlyone.gsm' (language 'en')
[Feb 21 22:28:47] VERBOSE[18929][C-00000001] file.c:     -- <SIP/ast2_g722-00000001> Playing 'confbridge-join.gsm' (language 'en')
[Feb 21 22:28:48] VERBOSE[18929][C-00000001] file.c:     -- <Bridge/0x7fb3bc004528-input> Playing 'confbridge-join.gsm' (language 'en')
[Feb 21 22:28:53] DTMF[18929][C-00000001] channel.c: DTMF begin '2' received on SIP/ast2_g722-00000001
[Feb 21 22:28:53] DTMF[18929][C-00000001] channel.c: DTMF begin passthrough '2' on SIP/ast2_g722-00000001
[Feb 21 22:28:53] DTMF[18929][C-00000001] channel.c: DTMF end '2' received on SIP/ast2_g722-00000001, duration 100 ms
[Feb 21 22:28:53] DTMF[18929][C-00000001] channel.c: DTMF end accepted with begin '2' on SIP/ast2_g722-00000001
[Feb 21 22:28:53] DTMF[18929][C-00000001] channel.c: DTMF end passthrough '2' on SIP/ast2_g722-00000001
[Feb 21 22:28:53] DTMF[18929][C-00000001] channel.c: DTMF begin '0' received on SIP/ast2_g722-00000001
[Feb 21 22:28:53] DTMF[18929][C-00000001] channel.c: DTMF begin ignored '0' on SIP/ast2_g722-00000001
[Feb 21 22:28:53] DTMF[18929][C-00000001] channel.c: DTMF end '0' received on SIP/ast2_g722-00000001, duration 100 ms
[Feb 21 22:28:53] DTMF[18929][C-00000001] channel.c: DTMF end passthrough '0' on SIP/ast2_g722-00000001
[Feb 21 22:28:53] DTMF[18929][C-00000001] channel.c: DTMF begin '1' received on SIP/ast2_g722-00000001
[Feb 21 22:28:53] DTMF[18929][C-00000001] channel.c: DTMF begin ignored '1' on SIP/ast2_g722-00000001
[Feb 21 22:28:53] DTMF[18929][C-00000001] channel.c: DTMF end '1' received on SIP/ast2_g722-00000001, duration 100 ms
[Feb 21 22:28:53] DTMF[18929][C-00000001] channel.c: DTMF end passthrough '1' on SIP/ast2_g722-00000001
[Feb 21 22:28:55] VERBOSE[18929][C-00000001] file.c:     -- <Bridge/0x7fb3bc004528-input> Playing 'conf-hasleft.gsm' (language 'en')
[Feb 21 22:28:57] VERBOSE[18929][C-00000001] file.c:     -- <Bridge/0x7fb3bc004528-input> Playing 'confbridge-leave.gsm' (language 'en')
[Feb 21 22:28:58] VERBOSE[18929][C-00000001] pbx.c:     -- Executing [user_profile@confbridge:3] Hangup("SIP/ast2_g722-00000001", "") in new stack
```